# While importing in node js module not found error occurring

Tags: node.js, express

I am using module type in node
So exported the route
as
`export default router ;`

But while importing as

```
import authRouter from './Routes/AuthRoute.js';
```

Module not found error occurs
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try removing the `.js` extension: `import authRouter from './Routes/AuthRoute';`

Comment: not worked   , i tried it

Comment: can you add `logs` and `command` for running to your question?